# Access Mongodb's 'db' in routers, NodeJS/Express

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm unable to export the db object for using in my routers (controller). Heres the file where i connect to the database and attempt to export db object:

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient
, assert = require('assert');

// Connection URL
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/database';

// Use connect method to connect to the server
var database;

MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
  assert.equal(null, err);
  console.log("Connected successfully to server");

  database =  db;
  module.exports = database;
});
```

and where i try using it in one of my routers:

```
var db = require('../path/to/file/above');

// Redirect to application
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    try {
        db.close();
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
    res.render('index',{});
});
```

---

"console.log(err)" says "db.close() is not a function".

**Q: How do i properly export the db object so i can use it in my routers?**

Answer (score 0):

i think there is some problem with your module.exports try this

```
    var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient
    , assert = require('assert');

    // Connection URL
    var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/database';

    // Use connect method to connect to the server
    var database;

    function connectMongo(cb){
        MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
          assert.equal(null, err);
          console.log("Connected successfully to server");

          cb(db);
        });
    }

    module.exports = connectMongo;
```

Comment: Wouldn't this also result in multiple connections to the database (at least one per router, assuming 1 connection per require)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [mongoskin](https://github.com/kissjs/node-mongoskin) to access the mongodb and can export the db object.

e.g.

```
var mongo = require('mongoskin');
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/database';

var db = mongo.db(url, {native_parser:true});

module.exports = db;
```

And, in your router,

```
var db = require('../path/to/file/above');

// Redirect to application
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  try {
    //some db operations
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
  res.render('index',{});
});
```

Other solution is to pass the callback as suggested by @Asif.

Answer (score 0):

This is what my database file (database.js) ended up to be:

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient
  , assert = require('assert');

var express = require('express');
var app = express();

// Connection URL
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/database';

// Use connect method to connect to the server
var database;

MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
    assert.equal(null, err);
    database = db;
});

// Returns DB object when called
module.exports.get = function() {
    return database;
}
```

and using it like this (note that you have to call the get function in a router.get() for example, calling it directly won't work since the connection won't be open yet):

```
var database = require('./database.js');
var assert = require('assert');
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

// Redirect to application
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    var db = database.get();
    // Mongo Query here
    res.render('index',{});
});
```